# How to simulate multivariate posterior distribution with a flat prior in general?

Tags: bayesian, simulation, posterior, computational-statistics

If I know that the posterior $p(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m|y)$ can be written $p(\theta_1|\theta_2,\dots,\theta_m,y)p(\theta_2|\theta_3,\dots,\theta_m|y)\dots p(\theta_m|y)$ where $p(\cdot|y)$  in each factor is known, then I simulate posterior by drawing posterior $\theta_m$ first, $\theta_{m-1}$,... and last $\theta_1$.

However, $p(\theta_m|y)$ is truly computed from $p(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m|y)$ by marginalization and one has to be able to write down the full likelihood explicitly for this case.

$Q:$ Is writing down full posterior likelihood required to do simulation? My guess is that checking proper posterior requires me writing down the likelihood.

$Q':$ How does one simulate posterior $p(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m|y)$ without writing down the full likelihood? I have seen in BDA 3rd Edition Chapter 3 pg 76 by sampling from joint posterior distribution which generate posterior on a discrete grid which is approximating distribution by sums of indicators functions with support on grids. Then it will generate $p(\theta_m|y)$ by directly marginalizing of the aforementioned discretized multivariate distribution on grid and this will allow drawing sample $\theta_m$. Then iteratively, one can condition on slice of coordinates to allow further drawing $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{m-1}$. The main issue of discretization is curse of dimensionality where for a not very high dimensional posterior(say $m=10$), one may need to create a grid of $10^{10}$ sampling points for sampling 10 points along each axis.

Comment: The decomposition into marginal, first conditional, second conditional &tc. is only useful when simulating from these directly. Otherwise an MCMC scheme can make a proposal on all components at once.

Comment: @Xi'an I see. Thanks. I think I will check relevant parts on MCMC in BDA then.